# Is it safe to open a crypted file with a text editor

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

Say I have files encrypted and I open them with a text editor, am I in risk of those files being copied in some temp memory ? 
I noticed this sentence in the introduction on truecrypt website

"Note that TrueCrypt never saves any decrypted data to a disk – it only stores them temporarily in RAM (memory). Even when the volume is mounted, data stored in the volume is still encrypted"

But do I understand it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file stored in a TrueCrypt volume is opened in a text editor (or any application really), the decrypted file is temporarily stored in RAM. Once in RAM, another application could potentially copy the data if it can locate the files contents in memory. The feasibility of this is highly dependent on the operating system you're using though.

Also, the editor you've opened the decrypted file in *may* save a copy of it to a non-encrypted disk. Once you've opened a file in an application it can do anything it wants with the data, it doesn't matter where the data originally came from or in what form it was stored.

Last, depending on your operating system, the OS itself may leave traces of encrypted files. For example, Windows keeps a list of recently opened files, and while this doesn't leave decrypted file contents lying around, it does reveal the names of any files from the TrueCrypt volume that were opened.

Comment: I see, say I would use a Ubuntu bootable usb stick, this stick would have an OS partition and another crypted partition with the data... I would open the file with say vi or emacs...

Comment: I can't comment as to exactly how Ubuntu and VI work internally, but it sounds like there could still be potential for accessing the decrypted file contents (although it's probably very unlikely). Ubuntu or VI could save some information about the file back to the USB stick.